Closed linear span and space of infinite linear combination
Let $\{Y_{n}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be a sequence in an infinite-dimensional
Lebesgue space $L^{p}(\mathsf{\Omega},\mathcal{F},\mathrm{P})$ on some
probability space $(\mathsf{\Omega},\mathcal{F},\mathrm{P})$. We say
$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}Y_{n}$ converges in $L^{p}$, if
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{N}a_{n}Y_{n}\overset{L^{p}}{\rightarrow}Y\in L^{p}\text{ as
}N\rightarrow\infty
$$
for $\mathbf{a}=(a_{1},a_{2},\cdots,a_{n},\cdots)\in\ell^{\infty}$, then we
write $Y=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}Y_{n}$.
We make the following assumptions

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left\vert Y_{n}\right\vert $ converges in $L^{p}$,
thus $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}Y_{n}$ converges in $L^{p}$ for any
$\mathbf{a}\in\ell^{\infty}$.

$\{Y_{n}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is linearly independent, thus
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}Y_{n}=0\iff a_{n}=0\text{ for all }n
$$


Define
$$
X_{1}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}Y_{n}\in L^{p}
$$
and $X_{n}=Y_{n}$ when $n\geq2$. Let
$$
\mathsf{A}_{m}=\left\{  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}X_{n}:\mathbf{a}=(a_{1}
,a_{2},\cdots)\in\ell^{\infty},\left\Vert \mathbf{a}\right\Vert \leq
m\right\}  \qquad\qquad m=1,2,\cdots
$$
and
\begin{align*}
\mathsf{Z}  & =\mathrm{csp}(X_{1},X_{2},X_{3},\cdots)\\
\mathsf{Y}  & =\mathrm{csp}(Y_{1},Y_{2},Y_{3},\cdots)
\end{align*}
where $\mathrm{csp}(\cdot)$ means closed linear span.
Question:

Is it true that $\mathsf{Y}=\mathsf{Z}$

$\mathsf{A}_{1}$ is closed in $L^{p}(\mathsf{\Omega},\mathcal{F}
,\mathrm{P})$ or not?

If $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}nY_{n}$ converges, is it in $\mathsf{Y}$? Where
$a_{n}=n$ and thus $\mathbf{a}\notin\ell^{\infty}$



For question $1$: Yes. $X_1 = \sum_{n=1}^\infty Y_n = \lim_{N \to \infty} \sum_{n=1}^N Y_n \in \mathsf{Y}$. And $Y_1 = X_1 - \sum_{n=2}^\infty X_n = \lim_{N \to \infty} (X_1 - \sum_{n=1}^N X_n) \in \mathsf{Z}$.
For question $3$: Yes. $\sum_{n=1}^\infty nY_n = \lim_{N \to \infty} \sum_{n=1}^N nY_n \in \mathsf{Y}$.
Now onto the more interesting question $2$. For $1 \leq p < \infty$, let $q$ be such that $\frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{q} = 1$. For $f \in L^q$, $g \in L^p$, let $\langle f, g \rangle = \int fg \, dP$. Recall that for each $f \in L^q$, $\langle f, \cdot \rangle$ is a continuous linear functional on $L^p$ and in fact all continuous linear functional arises this way. Now, fix $f \in L^q$. Since $\sum_{n=1}^\infty |Y_n|$ converges in $L^p$, we have,
$$\begin{split}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty |\langle f, Y_n \rangle| &\leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty \langle |f|, |Y_n| \rangle\\
&= \lim_{N \to \infty} \langle |f|, \sum_{n=1}^N |Y_n| \rangle\\
&= \langle |f|, \sum_{n=1}^\infty |Y_n| \rangle\\
&\leq \|f\|_{L^q}\|\sum_{n=1}^\infty |Y_n|\|_{L^p}\\
&< \infty
\end{split}$$
That is to say, for any $f \in L^q$, $(\langle f, Y_n \rangle)_n \in \ell^1$. Since $X_n = Y_n$ for all $n \geq 2$, we also have $(\langle f, X_n \rangle)_n \in \ell^1$. Consider the map $T: \ell^\infty \to L^p$ given by $T((a_n)_n) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nX_n$. Then,
$$\langle f, T((a_n)_n) \rangle = \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n \langle f, X_n \rangle$$
is a continuous linear functional on $\ell^\infty$ induced by an element $(\langle f, X_n \rangle)_n$ of $\ell^1$. Since the dual space of $\ell^1$ is $\ell^\infty$, this shows $T$ is weak$^\ast$-to-weak continuous. Since $B_m = \{(a_n)_n: \|(a_n)_n\|_{\ell^\infty} \leq m\}$ is weak$^\ast$-compact by Banach–Alaoglu theorem, $\mathsf{A}_m = T(B_m)$ is weakly compact, therefore weakly closed, and therefore closed.
(Note that this does not mean that $\cup_{m=1}^\infty \mathsf{A}_m = \{\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nX_n: (a_n)_n \in \ell^\infty\}$ is closed. In fact, if, say, $\sum_{n=1}^\infty nX_n$ converges in $L^p$, then it is in the closure of $\cup_{m=1}^\infty \mathsf{A}_m$ but not in $\cup_{m=1}^\infty \mathsf{A}_m$ itself.)

What is "weak*-to-weak continuous"? Why $T$ is "weak*-to-weak continuous"? Is $T$ "weak*-to-norm ($L^p$) continuous"

@ChenDeng-Ta As the name suggests, “weak$^\ast$-to-weak continuous” just means the map is continuous when the domain is equipped with the weak$^\ast$-topology and the codomain is equipped with the weak topology. I provided a proof as to why $T$ is weak$^\ast$-to-weak continuous in the answer. If you need clarification on that, please be more specific as to which part you are not understanding. And as to whether it is weak$^\ast$-to-norm continuous, I don’t know, but probably it’s not, I’d assume.

weak*: $\forall\mathbf{b}\in\ell^{1},\left\langle \mathbf{b},\mathbf{a}
{k}\right\rangle \rightarrow\left\langle \mathbf{b},\mathbf{a}\right\rangle
\implies\mathbf{a}{k}\overset{\ast}{\rightharpoonup}\mathbf{a}\in\ell
^{\infty}$, for $\left\langle \cdot,\mathbf{a}\right\rangle $ is continuous on
$\ell^{1}$. weak: $\forall f\in L^{q},\left\langle f,T(\mathbf{a}
{k})\right\rangle \rightarrow\left\langle f,T(\mathbf{a})\right\rangle
\implies T(\mathbf{a}{k})\rightharpoonup T(\mathbf{a})\in L^{p}$, since
$\left\langle f,\cdot\right\rangle $ is continuous.

Question: the map $T:\ell^{\infty
}\rightarrow L^{p}$ is weak*-to-weak continuous, it will map a weak*-compact
set to a weakly compact set.

@ChenDeng-Ta Yes. That is what weak$^\ast$ and weak convergence mean, respectively.

@ChenDeng-Ta Any continuous function maps a compact set onto a compact set. This is a standard fact in general topology, which you can find in, say, Wikipedia (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_space).
